# How can I use a variable (Bool) in my app to control whether remote notifications can show up when the app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a Global boolean "b". There's an available switch in the app which sets b to true or false.

When false, or unavailable, I don't want the app notifying the user of remote notifications. I have figured this out for the local alert, but how can I implement this for the backgrounded notification?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really control this 100% from your app. You can use silent remote notifications which you then convert into local notifications in your app (or not, depending on your Boolean value) but if your app is terminated then the notification will be delivered directly to the user, not your app.

The only way you can control it 100% is to save the Boolean on your push server and not actually send the notification.